# Service error: onEdit script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a basic `onEdit` script to run to automatically sort a column by date ascending. This script was working fine for several weeks but as of last Friday 10/31/14 I am getting service errors. I have been unable to determine the cause. Any ideas would greatly be appreciated. Below is the code.

```
/**
 * Automatically sorts the 6th column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sn = sa.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sn.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 6;
  var tableRange = "A2:I200"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sn.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it worked fine. You might want to check the *Google Apps Script Dashboard*, see reference.

You can make use of the `onEdit(e)` though, see the code I've prepared.

### Code

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();

  if(editedCell == 6) { 
    sh.getRange("A2:I200").sort({column: editedCell, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

### Reference

- [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit)
- [events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [dashboard](https://script.google.com/dashboard)